# ActiveAdmin Rails edit/delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using ActiveAdmin for a rails application (very impressed so far).

My question is, when I let it do it's default thing, it displays all the fields plus 3 other links that allow me to 'edit' / 'delete' that item. However if I modify the ActiveAdmin.register [resource] bit, the 'edit'/'delete' lines disappear in the output.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Highscore do
    index do
        column :id
        column :user
        column :score
        column :level
        column :created_at
        column :updated_at
    end
end
```

How do I link to the edit/delete stuff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try some code like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Highscore do
    index do
        column :id
        column :user
        column :score
        column :level
        column :created_at
        column :updated_at
        default_actions
    end
end
```

You can also add custom actions by following this [wiki page](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Add-custom-actions-and-buttons).